# How can I create an xml schema to accept multiple instances of the same element?

Tags: xml, xsd

I've seen several questions related to this, but their scenarios almost always know in advance the names of the elements. For example, the coder knows that [the "day" element will be one of seven days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177945/how-to-define-multiple-elements-in-xml-schema-with-the-same-name-and-different-a), or that [the "language" element will be one of a select group of languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354787/xsd-two-elements-with-the-same-name-but-different-attribute-value). My problem is that I do not know in advance what the sub-elements of my repeated element will be, or how many of them there will be.

My end goal is to use the schema to get the weather report into Excel, towards which I've been partially successful.

I'm trying to write a schema for the following xml snippet (from a weather report):

```
<area>
    <areaDesc>Area Name</areaDesc>
    <polygon>Ordered Pairs</polygon>
</area>
<area>
    <areaDesc>Second Area Name</areaDesc>
    <polygon>Ordered Pairs</polygon>
</area>
```

(The "polygon" element is a set of lat-long coordinates that create a polygonal area that is affected by the reported weather.)

There will be at least one area in the report, but no upper limit as far as I know. Since it's not possible to know all the possible area names, nor can I know how many areas will be in the report, the questions I linked to earlier don't really match my scenario.

The schema I have so far only uses the first area:

```
<xs:element name="area">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="areaDesc" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="polygon" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I just started using XML three days ago, so the answer may be obvious to anyone with more than a week's experience, or it may not even be possible. But hey, at least I'm aware of what I don't know so far.

Comment: Please show a complete, well-formed XML instance document and a complete XSD document. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It is trivial to have a container element for your `area` element and define it to contain a sequence of `area` elements. You might want to start with the primer on schemas https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#groups to get an idea and some samples.

Answer (score 0):

You're on track.  Don't worry that you cannot further restrict `areaDesc` beyond being an unconstrained `xs:string`.   That's common and completely acceptable for data such as names or descriptions where there can be no enumerable set of values known a priori.

Do note that you'll need a container element for the `area` elements because an XML document must have a single root element.